# Best URL method for categories

Tags: seo

We are working on a news website, we have a `country` category as a parent and then a `city` child sub category.

**Which method would be best for SEO?**

1. view/uk, view/uk/london
2. view/country/uk, view/city/london
3. view/uk, view/london

Most of the team went with option 3 since it's easier, but wanted to hear your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget SEO for a moment: the browsing directory of your site should make sense (from a logic perspective) and be clear enough for your visitors to use it.

Being that said, my personal recommendation would be the first option. Short and straight to the point.

- view/uk/
- view/uk/london
- view/uk/...

Don't forget to use [breadcrumb structured data](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/breadcrumb) to help searches understand your internal structure.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply and it makes sense, I guess it's more about logic here. We do have breadcrumbs as well as so the user know's where they are.